# Unable To Disconnect Docker Container From Network

Tags: networking, docker

I am **trying to disconnect** a Docker container (ContainerA1) connected to a network (NetworkA), but am unable to do so, even with the `--force` flag.

```
$ docker network disconnect NetworkA ContainerA1
```

I get an error response: `container c5d345a09c6d is not connected to the network`. (container IDs trimmed for brevity).

Oddly enough, I am **able to disconnect other containers** from NetworkA.

I inspected the network using `docker network inspect NetworkA`. I see :

```
[
    {
        "Name": "NetworkA",
        "Id": "9e4895ee72a1648ad10f297357447529b277beb92fe21069a244a8265b8f7306",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {
            "aded6369aef63b5237a7f543333f0b7fafbe2f01496efb2012bb7f5d67f14268": {
                "Name": "ContainerA2",
                "EndpointID": "c93b9dde46884181ca5acb63c03b2fb5fb3141e98416dda3e6cbc98b166b88ee",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ep-0f7d832a8d0cd86d8655ea9e0c1f7bbf33f1102b7bbe6454aca1ab8a48a6e4cd": {
                "Name": "ContainerA1",
                "EndpointID": "0f7d832a8d0cd86d8655ea9e0c1f7bbf33f1102b7bbe6454aca1ab8a48a6e4cd",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:07",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.7/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Notice the `ep-` prefix for ContainerA1.

I tried removing the container, but still see it in the list of containers when I do `docker network inspect NetworkA`. The "EndpointID" is different from the container ID, but having same name.

How can I **remove stale entries from network**, NetworkA?

Comment: Seems to be an active endpoint (ep): https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19261